# Orthogonal Vector using Projection

Tags: vectors

I have the following two vectors:

$$\vec a = \begin{pmatrix}0.0\\ 6.0\\ 0.0\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\vec b = \begin{pmatrix}-4.0\\ 8.0\\ 0.0\end{pmatrix}$$

These are just examples, I am looking to solve this issue for all 3D vectors.

So with these vectors, I want to create a vector $\vec c$ that is Orthogonal to $\vec a$ and intersects with $\vec b$ by getting the correct points on $\vec a$ and $\vec b$.

Basically, in this scenario I want the resulting vector: $\vec c = (-3.0, 0, 0)^\top$.

Right now, I can easily get the point on $\vec a$ (projb), by projecting $ \vec  b$ onto a and then scaling down based on the magnitude of the vectors. However, I have no idea how to get the second point.

The following picture will hopefully illustrate my issue ($\vec a$: blue, $\vec b$: green):
[image: Drawing to illustrate the points I need to calculate]

I am not sure how to create a vector that is orthogonal to a, and even if I could create an infinite orthogonal vector to a from the point I would still need to figure out the intersection point / magnitude of my new vector.

Hopefully some of you can help me out.

Comment: What do you mean by "intersects with" in this context?

Comment: So you are searching for some scalar multiple of the orthogonal component $b-(b\cdot a)a$?

Comment: Oops! Unless $a$ is a unit vector that needs to be $b-\frac{b\cdot a}{a\cdot a}\,a$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales my calculations might be off, but using that formula I get -4, 0, 0 and not -3, 0, 0.

Comment: @AlexProvost I just want the vector C to go from point "projb" to point "???" of the drawing. Thus the intersection point is "???".

Comment: @SimonLanghoff I think you mean to say that the vector $a+c$ intersects the line spanned by $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ??? of your picture is the destination of your vector $\vec c$ and it starts at the $\vec a$
I think you got the equations that
$$\vec a+\vec c=\lambda \vec b \tag{1}$$
wiht $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ for the "intersection" and
$$\vec a\cdot \vec c=0\tag{2}$$
from the orthogonality.

Then you can insert the concrete values into (1)
$$\vec c=\lambda \begin{pmatrix}-4\\8\\0\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}0\\6\\0\end{pmatrix}$$
From (2) and $\vec a = \begin{pmatrix}0\\6\\0\end{pmatrix}$you can see that $c_y=0$
This means $$6-\lambda8=0$$
$$\lambda =\frac34$$
and thus
$$\vec c=\frac34\begin{pmatrix}-4\\8\\0\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}0\\6\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-3\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

**Edit**

If you want to solve it in algorithm you can use $$\lambda=\frac{\vec a^2}{\vec a\cdot \vec b}$$
to get the lambda then use $\vec c=\lambda\vec b -\vec a$
You can use this for your program.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am to solve this using a programming language (Pawn) which does not have a solver or any library useful for equations. Is it possible to solve without "solving for x"? If that makes any sense?.

Comment: @SimonLanghoff See **Edit**